# Streaming video to Android

Tags: video

Does Android natively support any type of streaming video similar to m3u8 on iPhone? Looking for a solution that handles HTTP Streaming or Progressive download with an option to deliver multiple quality of streams and change between the different quality levels while playback. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like this question should have been asked on **StackOverflow** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports the RTSP protocol (I believe using [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)), I'm not sure if this has everything you're looking for.

Comment: That's not true VideoView does not support RTSP!

Comment: @Ghassen OK, do you know what does? [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) states very clearly that Android supports RTSP, so how do you handle it if not via VideoView?

Comment: [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) mentions using RTSP URIs, and the page says "An example on how to use the methods in this class can be found in VideoView."